# Cannot commit to SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Today I faced with a problem: cannot commit my local Android projects changes to svn.
Team -> Update and Team-> Clean Up didn't help me.
I don't get any messages. I click commit and see Show History -> my changes are not committed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably get a hint by looking at the svn-console, and showing us what you get there: A random google-image to find the console:

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/images/svn_console.png

If you have that console (should be on the bottom of your screen, otherwise try and find it with the window->show-view menu), but it's not showing anything SVN-related, you can press the button just left of the "minimize" button: It will give you some options ('new console view', 'java stack trace' and hopefully 'svn').

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Reason for me - 403 Forbidden
I found that Error Log shows this information too.