# How to use SVN (Apache SubverSion) in android project to maintain the version

Tags: java, android

I want to use SVN (Apache SubverSion) on my android project. To maintain version of the application. Can any one please tell me what are the step by step procedure to Install and use the SVN In the project. I am using Eclipse Helios (3.6).

Thanks In advance..

Answer (score 2):

Commit everything into the SVN except gen folder...don't update gen folder inside SVN because gen folder contain .apk file and it generate automatically everytime when you clean or rebuild your project and do have a look at the following links:

[Cannot commit to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399175/cannot-commit-to-svn)

http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/02/android-using-svn-with-your-apps-project-and-eclipse/

http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/eclipse-android-svn-fail/

Comment: Don't add gen and bin folders...Both should not be there in SVN

Answer (score 0):

SVN is one option... but I found git to be more trustworthy, powerful and easy to use.  I know this does not answer your question directly, but this is the best advice I can give you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. @Jaco. I just want maintain my programs version can please tell how can I do this by using GIT. It is not compulsory to use SVN if by using git my purpose is served then I will use that can you please tell me about this.

Comment: I would check in the code once I am happy with the code.  Create a branch with a version name and viola, i.e. git branch <version>. See the numerous tutorials on git on the web.

Comment: I find it very humorous how the votes on this answer is jumping up and down.  Seems like a tug-of-war between the SVN and GIT advocates  :)

Comment: I also don't know?? what'shappening.