# SVN commit error with Eclipse Indigo, Android with ADT-Plugin

Tags: android, svn

I have errors when trying to commit saying transaction is out of date...

but I think it has something to do with the automatic generation of resource files for Android.

Does anyone else have this problem or have suspicions about what is going on?

Comment: ru tying to commit all your project? just do it by src folder and res folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should see these links:

[Cannot commit to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399175/cannot-commit-to-svn)

[Android: Using SVN with your app’s project (and eclipse)](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/02/android-using-svn-with-your-apps-project-and-eclipse/)

[Eclipse + Android + SVN = fail](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/eclipse-android-svn-fail/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: cool, got it to work using your 2nd link... info there saying _Don’t include the files inside /bin or /gen as they are just build from the source code and will simply fill up a lot space in your SVN. But do include the folders themselves as the project will fail to build without them._ however, I don't quite understand how to implement the last part in Eclipse... I set under preferences so it will ignore bin and gen folders for all my projects... but I think this means it will not recreate the bin and gen folders? is there a way to set it to ignore everything in bin/gen but not the folders?

Comment: @ycomp: Personally, I've never used SVN as such cuz I work solo. But as far as I understand, you should simply create empty folders _/bin and /gen_ and just leave it. Commit rest of the folders and files _esp. the /src and /res_ as they contain core files. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, usually with deleted packages which have deleted files inside. I don't know why this happens, but for me it works like:

1. First commit the file deletions.
2. Override and update the packages
3. Delete the packages
4. Commit package deletion

PS: I personally do not version the auto-generated resources by Android SDK (since they're auto-generated...). I suggest you ignore Android's auto-generated classes, folders and packages.